# Is it possible to access anything inside QScriptValue holding QVariantMap from qml?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

Hi there I want pass javascript function to c++ code from qml and later call it, but stuck with QScriptValue holding QVariantMap, which dont want to be accessed from javascript. Am I doing everything in right way and can I do what I want without hacks? Im using QtQuick1.1 and Qt 5.5.0.

I have c++ class with method:

```
void SomeClass::setQmlCallback(const QScriptValue &fn)
{
    QScriptValue scriptFn = fn;
    QScriptValueList args;

    QVariantMap m;
    m.insert(QStringLiteral("a"), 96);
    m.insert(QStringLiteral("b"), 97);
    args << scriptFn.engine()->newVariant(m); // To pass VariantMap to qml I wrap it in ScriptValue

    scriptFn.call(scriptFn, args);
}
```

And some qml code:

```
onSomethingHappend: {
SomeClass.setQmlCallback(function(row) {
//        console.log(row.a); // NotOk
//        row's key `a` is undefined here
        var convertedToVariant = SomeClass.convertToVariant(row);
        console.log(convertedToVariant.a); // Ok
});
}
```

Hack to explicitly convert ScriptValue to Variant:

```
QVariant SomeClass::convertToVariant(const QVariant &v)
{
        return v;
}
```

Also if I will pass QString instead of QVariantMap everything will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know why, but changing `QScriptEngine::newVariant` to `QScriptEngine::toScriptValue` solves the issue so I can access passed QVariantMap as js object without hacks.